# Varchar to datetime data type conversion resulting in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I want to insert the data in SQL database but in SQL query the date format can not be inserted.
SQL query is the following:

```
string query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details(status_id,remark,inserted_by,inserted_date)VALUES('" + StatusDropDownList.SelectedValue + "','" + remarkTextArea.Content + "','" + Session["user_id"] + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

And it shows the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

So what can I do with the datetime format?

Comment: Don't use a varchar type to store dates. Don't use string concatenation to create SQL queries. Google for `Bobby Tables`. Use parameterize queries

Comment: sqlserver <> mysql

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's MySQL or SQL Server. SQL Injection works the same in both databases. The solution just as easy in both cases

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I believe scsimon is referring to the fact that both databases are tagged in the OP's question. The syntax of the SQL can vary between the two.

Comment: @AnthonyT. I know, but that's trivial compared to the actual problem. I could put `',NULL,NULL); DELETE FROM tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details;--` in that remarks field. Besides, the syntax is the same in this case - MySQL accepts named parameters with the `@` prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thank You so much. Its work

Comment: @PMohite no it doesn't. When I put `',NULL,NULL); DELETE FROM tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details;--` in the remarks field I get no error. I also get an empty screen. Fix your query. Use parameterized queries. Changing the sting format isn't a solution, it's simply a hack to bypass just *one* of the issues caused by string concatenation